# ReactJS screen follows element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my app, when viewing a restaurant page, comments are hidden by default. The user can expand them as desired. I want the screen to slide down smoothly behind the bottom edge of the comments window when the comment box is maximized.

When opening the page:
[image]

When expanding comments:
[image]

That's what I need:
[image]

When rolled back, the screen moves smoothly with the bottom edge of the window. I'd like to achieve the same effect when unwrapping.

I implemented folding and expanding in this way:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isOpen) {
        innerWindowRef.current.setAttribute('style', 'height:' + totalCommentHeight.current + 'px')
        outWindowRef.current.setAttribute('style', 'padding: 5px')
    } else {
        innerWindowRef.current.setAttribute('style', 'height: 0; padding: 0')
        setTimeout(() => outWindowRef.current.setAttribute('style', 'padding: 5px 5px 0'), 900)
    }
}, [isOpen])
```

I tried to use the scrollTo() function, but it did not suit me because it only works with elements that have already been drawn, and not with those that are being drawn (expanded) at the moment. Therefore, I was able to implement this option only with a delay, which did not suit me.

The same goes for the scrollIntoView() function.

It is necessary that the screen always scrolls to the bottom of the page at the same speed as the animation of the expanding window. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

This should solves your problem:

```
window.scrollBy({
  top: 100, // this is the amount to be added to the current scroll. it can be negative or positiove number (in px)
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

You need to give the height of the expanded comment block to top as value